# How to replace a message for a locked user in SAP Logon?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

We lock all business/developer SAP users for each system copy/upgrade session. The users are informed in advance about the planned works, but some of them  try to logon into the system. They see SAP standard message that the user is locked and ask 1st level support to unlock the user. As result our 1st level support gets a plenty of 'please unlock' messages.

A solution is to replace SAP standard message with text 'your user is locked because of copy/upgrade works' for a period of system copy/upgrade. I know that I can change SAP GUI logon screen text, but is there any option to replace SAP standard message for locked users? Is it possible to show another message before/after the SAP standard one?

I tryed to use user exit in FM EXIT_SAPLSUSF_001, but the FM works for unlocked users only.

Comment: Give the screenshot how is your lock message look like. [Like this](http://www.sapbasistuts.com/_/rsrc/1354208190596/home/os-administration/tools/sap-mass-user-lock-unlock-at-os-level/SAP_Lgon_Not_Allowed_message.png)?

Comment: No it doesn't. It's 'Your user has been locked. Contact your administrator', but I need the message from your screenshot.'

Comment: See if this article helps you: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/18/change-the-authentication-error-messages-text-on-logon-page-for-sap-netweaver-portal-73/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However this is valid for NetWeaver portal web users only. I'm asking about ERP users who work via SAP GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is easily changeable. Admin lock message is contained in message class 00 number `158`, password lock in number `200` (see SAP note [939017](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/939017)).

Message classs 00 is not treated like system object and can be changed even without SSCR key

[image]

results in

[image]